# Xcode 7 Beta 5, UITableViewCells subviews are clipped out of ContentView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios9, xcode7

I've been having issues with `UITableViewCells` as a few others have been (from what I can see on StackOverflow), and I've followed the fixes suggested in those other threads, but I've an issue which refuses to be rectified by those in the similar questions.

I've attached a screenshot of the issue below, the subviews are being resized and having their coordinates located out of the ContentView of the `UITableViewCell`, when I look into the view debugger I can see that they are being clipped out when I turn on **Show clipped content**.

Any ideas? I've tried redoing all of the constraints, I've tried rebuilding the entire `UIView` but nothing rectifies the issue. The views that are not shown are the labels (shown below as clipped "L", "0" and "5").

Screenshot of the View Hierarchy
[image]

Screenshot from the iPhone
[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot from the simulator?

Comment: Attached a screenshot from the iPhone

Comment: I don't know what object is not shown, but I had similiar problem, using a size class solved it.

Comment: I'm already using size classes, I'll try a different one and see what happens I guess

Comment: So after trying different size classes and even rebuilding the view controller as a `UITableViewController` (before it was a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`) the issue is still persisting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by replacing the Storyboard constraints with programmatic constraints. It seems it just did not want to recognise the storyboard ones for some reason.